# Encrypting sections of XML files

Tags: xml, encryption

I'm extremely new to *designing* XML documents, so I'm looking for a suggestion of how to do what I need to do.

I'm designing an application that will use config/license files.  Due to some intellectual property issues, we'd like the ability to encrypt sections of the file.  We'd also like to have the option to not encrypt the files for internal use.  Ideally, I'd like to have a tag in the file that says whether the next section is encrypted or not.  What I'm struggling with is:

1. Is this possible?
2. How do I write the schema for it?

As an example, assume this is my data that's necessary for our file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <number>1</number>
  <text>Hello</text>
</data>
```

I'd really like to add an "encrypted" tag that behaves like so when encrypted is **false**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<encrypted>false</encrypted>
<data>
  <number>1</number>
  <text>Hello</text>
</data>
```

And when it's **true**, the same data is encrypted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<encrypted>true</encrypted>
<data>
  asdcnalsdfypaoweht=40571roic-8934y
</data>
```

So the data tag includes encrypted/unencrypted data based on the value of the encrypted tag.  Is it possible to write a single schema that does this?  Or should I write two schemas:

1. One schema is for the unencrypted file (so the <number> and <text> tags in the above example
2. The second schema would define a file that only has two tags <encrypted> and <data>.  If encrypted is false, I just include the entire encrypted XML file inside the data tag.  But if encrypted is true, I include the encrypted version of the file inside the data tag.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: `<element encrypted="true"> content_text_or_base64_data` ?

Comment: So are you saying I should go with my two schema idea?  One to define/validate the actual file, and then a separate one to define/validate the data?

Comment: I guess the real question I'm asking is more on the schema side, than the XML side.  How to define this concept so that I end up with well-formed XML that does what I want, and can use XML parsers/validators to verify the file(s)